# Атрибут rel "неправильное значение". Насколько критично для SEO?

Tags: seo, link, атрибуты

`Virtuemart` в карточках товара, на ссылки изображений навешивает `rel=vm-additional-images`. 
Валидатор на такое ругается.

> Error: Bad value vm-additional-images for attribute rel on element a: The string vm-additional-images is not a registered keyword.

Подскажите какую функцию в данном случае делает этот атрибут? 
И насколько это плохо для поисковиков?

Answer (score -1):

Не правильное значение атрибута.
Во-первых необходимо использовать значения [предусмотренные для rel](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values)

Атрибут rel не является обязательным и используется в качестве дополнительного уточнения, если есть несколько однотипных элементов.
В вашем случае атрибут не имеет смысла, можете удалить.